# How to keep question mark in URL rewriting with a GET method?

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

I am trying to use URL rewriting to rewrite

```
search-en.php?q=abc
```

to

```
pages-afficher-recherche.php?lang_abbreviation=en&q=abc
```

and I did

```
RewriteRule ^search-([a-zA-Z]{2})\.php\?q\=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ pages-afficher-recherche.php?lang_abbreviation=$1&q=$2 [L]
```

But I get 404 not found error.

How to keep the question mark in URL rewriting with a GET method?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have the PHP coffee assume a default value for that parameter?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Please can you show me how to do it ?

Comment: It seems that in order to use question marks in htaccess, you're generally supposed to use QUERY_STRING in you're RewriteRules. I don't use ? parameters so that's all I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^search-([a-zA-Z]{2})\.php\?q\=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ pages-afficher-recherche.php?lang_abbreviation=$1&q=$2 [L]
> ```

In order to check the query string part of the URL, you'll need to reference the `QUERY_STRING` server variable, as @Micheald suggested in comments. However, you need to use a *condition* (ie. `RewriteCond` directive), not the `RewriteRule` directive, in order to perform this check. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* checks against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string.

The above `RewriteRule` (that checks for a literal `?` in the *URL-path*) will never match, so the URL is never rewritten. So, assuming `/search-en.php?q=abc` doesn't exist, this simply triggers a 404.

However, the *substitution* can also be simplified, since you don't need to explicitly capture the query string (just *check* it). You simply want to append the query string that satisfies your condition to the end of the new query string, which is achieved with the `QSA` flag.

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=[\w-]*$
RewriteRule ^search-([a-zA-Z]{2})\.php$ pages-afficher-recherche.php?lang_abbreviation=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`\w` is a shorthand character class, which is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. The `QSA` (Query String Append) flag on the `RewriteRule` will copy the query string from the request (eg. `q=abc`) and append it to (and merge it with) the query string you have specified on the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.